# Worklight - Error ADMA0007E and ADMA0007E

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, jndi, worklight-server

I'm using worklight 6.1 for my mobile app project. My problem is I got this error when trying to upload .war file into websphere in step 7 according to this [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_deploying_customization_war_file_to_application_server.html).

```
ADMA0007E: A Validation error occurred in task Mapping resource references to resources. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified for reference binding jdbc/WorklightDS in module Worklight with EJB name . 

ADMA0007E: A Validation error occurred in task Mapping resource references to resources. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified for reference binding jdbc/WorklightReportsDS in module Worklight with EJB name .
```

I extract my .war file and open my web.xml. Then I got this details.

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>Worklight Server Database</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/WorklightDS</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
   <description>Reports Database</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/WorklightReportsDS</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

[image]

I had no idea regarding to this database. It's like reporting tools in worklight. Why it happen? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got the answer. I need to install worklight server first before deploy war file.

Answer (score 0):

The resource reference from your application doesn't match any resources defined in the websphere JNDI namespace. You have to define the connections to the database, give them a JNDI name and define them in the screen shown in your screenshot.